# Why do Firebase Database security rules not apply to an Authenticated REST API?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Database and have set one security rule for testing

```
".write":false
```

Reads are always true.

Now when I write anything with the client side SDK inside an android app, the write is denied everywhere in the database as expected.

However, when I use an authenticated REST API patch request to write anything anywhere, it always succeeds.

The token is generated as follows:

```
       //googleCredAhmedabad and scopedAhmedabad are GoogleCredential objects

       InputStream is = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/firebaseauth/myserviceaccountfile.json");

        googleCredAhmedabad = GoogleCredential.fromStream(is);

        scopedAhmedabad = googleCredAhmedabad.createScoped(
                Arrays.asList(
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database",
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
                        )
                );

        scopedAhmedabad.refreshToken();

        String myToken = scopedAhmedabad.getAccessToken();
```

Does an (credential is generated with enough scopes using service-account) authenticated REST API call trump security rules?

Comment: Maybe the security rules only apply to their client-side (android and ios) and web-side sdks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mentioned on the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#auth):

> The auth request parameter allows access to data protected by Firebase
>   Realtime Database Rules, and is supported by all request types. The
>   argument can either be our Firebase app secret or an authentication
>   token, which we'll cover in the user authorization section.

And I see you've mentioned that you're using an authenticated REST API, so I'm assuming you do have the auth parameter set. Which means you're right: the security rules do not apply to authenticated REST APIs.

Comment: Yep just tested without the auth token, as predicted doesn't work. I guess the default credential created using a service account gives full admin rights like the adminsdk. And unlike adminsdk, there's no override the auth possible :) somehow had missed that part in the docs, thanks :)